# Keycloak standalone HTTPS configuration throws error saying no keys found in keystore

Tags: ssl, https, keycloak, tls1.2, keytool

I am trying to configure keycloak https with SSL certificate based on the documentation

https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_installation/#_setting_up_ssl

while Keycloak 11.0 starts reports the following error

```
06:46:21,034 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([                         
    ("core-service" => "management"),                                                                                                                                  
    ("security-realm" => "UndertowRealm")                                                                                                                              
]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"org.wildfly.core.management.security.realm.UndertowRealm.key-manager" => "Failed to start service       
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in anonymous service: WFLYDM0083: The KeyStore /opt/keycloak-11.0.0/standalone/con
figuration/keycloak.jks does not contain any keys.                                                                                                                     
    Caused by: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in anonymous service: WFLYDM0083: The KeyStore /opt/keycloak-11.0.0/standalone/configuration/keycloak.jks does not 
contain any keys."}}
```

But am very sure , I have my certificate properly signed by my CA and the keystore is imported with respective root and domain certificate.

Infact i could able to list the keys in the keystore path mentioned in the path by following command.

`keytool list -keystore keycloak.kjs`

How else i can verify my keystore to address this issue.

Comment: it really looks like something is wrong with your keystore. can you post the output of `keytool list`?

Comment: Resolved the same , keytool list only shows certificates and not the private key itself. Moved to pkcs12 keystore with key and certificate association then it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved the same , keytool list only shows certificates and not the private key itself.

Moved to pkcs12 keystore with key and certificate association then it worked.